# What could be the reason I keep getting this CORS error?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I'm using react for my front end and laravel to verify a user as follows:

1. The user clicks on a link sent to their email. This is the structure of the url

`http://example.com/verify/?id=$2y$10$uUS8zNE6vpCu.DXd2jJtv..E4sSAA..5XQaw/oHOJaYjnHrCqiUs6`

2. React grabs the id and constructs a get request to the API whose domain has the structure: `api.example.com` as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import HeaderMobile from "./components/HeaderMobile";
import LeftSidebar from "./components/LeftSidebar";
import RightContentWrapper from "./components/RightContentWrapper";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import axios from "axios";
import "./RegisterStudent.css";
import { FaSpinner } from "react-icons/fa";
import Constants from "./Helpers/Constants";

// redux stuff
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { signUserIn } from "./Redux/Actions/";

export class Verify extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tokenError: false,
      verified: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const token = queryParams.get("id");

    axios
      .get(`${Constants.API_DOMAIN}/api/verify/?id=${token}`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          verified: true,
          networkError: false,
          tokenError: false,
        });

        window.location.href = `/login/?verified?=1`;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          tokenError: true,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <HeaderMobile />
          <LeftSidebar />
          <RightContentWrapper>
            <div className="sCard">
              <div className="cardHeading">
                <h5 className="text-uppercase">
                  Verifying your email address.
                </h5>

                {this.state.tokenError === false ? (
                  <div>
                    <p className="text-center">
                      Please wait while your email is being verified.
                    </p>
                    <FaSpinner className="spin centerize" />
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <p className="text-center">error</p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </RightContentWrapper>
        </Row>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ signUserIn }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Verify);
```

3. Laravel receives the request as follows:

In the `api.php` file:

```
Route::get('/verify', 'APIAuthController@verify')->name('verify')->middleware(['api']);
```

And the verify function is as follows:

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
  $user = User::where(['verification_token' => $request->id]);
  if($user->count() > 0) {
    $user = $user->first();
    $user->email_verified_at = Carbon::now();
    // $user->verification_token = null;
    $user->save();
    
    $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
    $user->getRoleNames(); // get role
    $response = ['token' => $token, 'user' => $user];

    // return response()->json($response, 200);
    return response()->json(200);
  } else {
    return response()->json(422);
  }
}
```

When I access the laravel api route directly (as opposed to from react), I get no error at all.

My Kernel.php already has FruitCake:

`\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,`

And the `config\cors.php` file remains untouched and looks like this:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

I encounter no CORS problems with post requests and with get requests that are accompanied by an access token (USING PASSPORT for authentication). Here's an example of a get route (in api.php) for an authenticated use that has no errors:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'role:admin|teacher|student|kid|parent']], function () {
  Route::get('school/learn/', 'SchoolController@getLearnPage')->name('getLearnPage');
});
```

React version: "^16.13.1"

Laravel Version: 7.30.4

Here's the CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.example.com/api/verify/?id=$2y$10$uUS8zNE6vpCu.DXd2jJtv..E4sSAA..5XQaw/oHOJaYjnHrCqiUs6' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (xhr.js:84)


GET http://api.example.com/api/verify/?id=$2y$10$uUS8zNE6vpCu.DXd2jJtv..E4sSAA..5XQaw/oHOJaYjnHrCqiUs6 net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: check the response header from laravel api send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header using postman or somehing

Comment: @bhucho I had no errors on postman but I've also managed to resolve the error after switching to post instead of get request.

Comment: using post I guess has solved because the browser sends a OPTIONS request to the server before sending the post request to check what is the value for Access-control-allow-origin that can be used to pass that value as post for get there is no OPTIONS request send to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite having set up laravel's `cors.php` correctly, I realized that there was still a cors error and it was due to a URL mismatch between the client's request url and the API endpoint. **The client (request) url should not have a trailing forward slash.**

```
axios.get(`${Constants.API_DOMAIN}/api/verify/?id=${token}`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
```

In the example above, you should remove the forward slash that comes after `/verify` and instead have the following:

```
axios
      .get(`${Constants.API_DOMAIN}/api/verify?id=${token}`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
```

The requesting URL supplied to axios should be an exact match to your API endpoint. Otherwise, you will run into a preflight request cors error especially when you have cookies in your request or your request is not simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out of my head, but maybe you should also add these attributes in your JS-code.

```
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'include', // Normally only if you are using sessions and no JWT tokens
  mode: 'cors', // Has to be set in older versions of MS Edge
  // ... 
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*', // Allow connection with external domain-name 
  }
});
```

Using CORS through HTTP can be problematic, this extension in Chrome may also be of help.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: I'll try switching to fetch and see if it helps.

Comment: @andromeda I have no experience with axios. But maybe the same attributes like mode, credentials, headers also work together with axios : )

Comment: The problem's been resolved but I'm not sure what it was because I only changed the request from get to post and rewrote the component again one step at a time. Still using axios though. I did see an answer on github that said axios doesn't have these options you've provided. The answer also said fetch works where axios fails because axios enforces CORS even when you don't want it to. I'll leave it at that for now and review fetch later.

Comment: I kept running into this issue - it would go away and reappear every so often. I provided an answer explaining what was going on.